# How to turn part of a movie sideways?

Tags: video

I have a movie on my phone about 5 minutes long. After about 2 minutes, the movie is upside down. How can I fix this without affecting the whole video?

I would like to turn the video sideways after 2 minutes.

Comment: Hi shadid, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Coudl you tell us what software you are using? That might help a lot in getting a nice answer. Thanks and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

You need to trim the clip into two then rotate the piece that needs to be rotated. I've had difficulty finding an app to rotate footage on phone. For trimming I use CuteCut. You could do it on the computer instead though using either Windows Movie Maker or Macs iMovie.